# Improve performance for last values aggregation on large existing dataset

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am doing aggregations on a big index (several terabytes, split in 100 gb sub-indices)
The query I am doing is to retrieve for each "tag" field value the most recent document.
My problem is the query is very slow (> 1 minute) and I have to run it several time with different (group) filters.

Example :

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {"bool": {
   "must": [
    {"match": {
      "group.keyword": "ZZZ"
    }},
    {
      "range": {
        "date": {
          "lt": "2023-02-02T00:00:00+0100"
        }
      }
    }
  ]}},
  "aggs": {
    "perTag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag.keyword",
        "size": 65000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "theLastOfValues": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{
              "date": {"order": "desc"}
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've found this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58838916/591922 , which says that a date sorted index could improve performance a lot.

But I've also found this in the documentation : "Sort in reindex is deprecated. Sorting in reindex was never guaranteed to index documents in order"

So if I can't reindex old documents, is there a way to apply a sort policy to index the new documents?

If so, would it be efficient and work to only look at the recently inserted documents (documents with recent dates) when I am looking to the most recent document for each tag value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the [`composite` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) which allows you to perform queries on a smaller dataset, yet allow you to paginate over all your tags more efficiently without having to retrieve all 65K tags in one go:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "group.keyword": "ZZZ"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "lt": "2023-02-02T00:00:00+0100"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 100,
        "sources": [
          {
            "perTag": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tag.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "theLastOfValues": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: It's been created exactly for this purpose and is the aggregation that powers the [Latest Transform API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html#latest-transform-overview)